# TemplateDoesNotExist graphene/graphiql.html

Tags: python, django, graphene-python, graphene-django

I'm trying to setup Graphene, but have a following exception raised when open http://localhost:8000/graphql/ in browser:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /graphql/
graphene/graphiql.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/graphql/
Django Version: 3.2.10
```

Added did whole setup, added to urls, configured schema, queries and mutations. But still not work. And even don't remember that ever needed to configure templates for Graphene.

Comment: Did you add graphene_django under apps in settings?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Accepted answer helped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like forgot to add following in `settings.py`, so it wasn't fully configured, at least for DEBUG mode:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    "graphene_django",
    # ...
]
```